# Why space is coming in between text using bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting so much space between the text. I am using form-group. I don't know why. I am new to Bootstrap.

[image: Screenshot of web app]

Code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
          <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
               <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-12">

                                   <div class="col-md-6">                             
                                        <div align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:50px;"><b>Exhibitors Passport</b> </div>              
                                  </div>
                                   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
                               </div>
                  </div>

              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <section class="container">
                      <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <h3 style="color:#fc2630;font-size:14px;padding-bottom:15px;">
                                                   Please Submit Exhibitor Passport Details :</h3>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                              <div class="col-md-6" style="color:#5a5b5b;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">
                                  Delegate Details - 1:
                                   <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1_" runat="server" Checked="True" Visible="False" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>


                  </section>
              </div>
          </asp:Panel>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not because of Bootstrap. You have some padding in your `style` attributes.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMbEbO